# Angular-leaflet. required by directive 'center'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm looking at this 2 repos :

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-leaflet

https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive

I installed the ui-leaflet : `bower install --save ui-leaflet`

I added the dependecy : `['ui-leaflet', ...]`

But in the browser's console I get this: `Controller 'leaflet', required by directive 'center', can't be found!`

How do I install this directive? Why is it necessary?

I think it's the 2nd repo but I don't get how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I also had the googlemaps' directive included...

I wanted to have 2 maps, the leaflet's one and the google's.
I realized it's a hustle to do this...